# Point mutation vs Indels

Tags: molecular-biology, mutations

DNA sequence of a gene can be altered in a number of ways. Gene mutations have varying effects on health, depending on where they occur and whether they alter the function of essential proteins.

I know that there different types of mutations.

Missense, Nonsense, Insertion, Deletion, Duplication, Silent, Frameshift indel, Repeat expansion, Inframe indel, stoploss, splicing.

Can anyone please tell me which mutations are Point mutations and which come under Indels?

Thank you

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [point mutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_mutation) is a mutation causing the substitution, insertion or deletion of a single nucleotide.

An [indel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indel) is a change in the number of nucleotides (either through insertion or deletion hence the name). When talking about indel most people (in evolutionary biology at least) refer to the insertion or deletion of a single nucleotide but some might refer to greater changes when talking about indels.

An indel which concern the insertion or deletion of a single nucleotide is a point mutation.